# projector (external/internal combo) icons while switching - how?

Tags: shortcut-keys, display, application-switcher

External vga connected monitor with laptop.

On windows when you press the projector hotkey/fn key on a laptop, you see a list of options or combinations of external projector and onboard screen, it looks like the `alt`-`tab` switcher on any desktop. That way, you know which combination you will get before you let go and can cycle through them in your own order, no need to try out each one to get to the one you want.

On ubuntu 12.04?